# Regular Expression for any number excluding specific numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to make a regular expression that captures every integer (both positive and negative) as long as it is not one of the following: -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, or 10.

So these should match: -11, 8, -4, 11, 15, 121, 3, etc.

So far, I have this regex: `/-?([^0|1|2|10])+/`

It captures the negative sign, but it still does it when the number is -2 or -1, which I don't want. Also, it doesn't capture 11.

How should I change the expression to match the numbers I want to find. Additionally, is there a better way to find those numbers in a string?

Answer (score 5):

> How should I change the expression to match the numbers I want to find. Additionally, is there a better way to find those numbers in a string?

Just use simple regex that'll match all the numbers from string and then filter the numbers

```
// Define the exclude numbers list:
// (for maintainability in the future, should excluded numbers ever change, 
// this is the only line to update)
var excludedNos = ['-2', '-1', '0', '1', '2', '10'];

var nos = (str.match(/-?\d+/g) || []).filter(function(no) {
    return excludedNos.indexOf(no) === -1;
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nufeanp9/)

Comment: var str = '-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, or 10 -11, 8, -4, 11, 15, 121, 3';
I get nos = ["2", "1", "0", "1", "2", "10", "11", "8", "4", "11", "15", "121", "3"]

Comment: @RichS Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6osg0fj3/), that's because the excludedNos array contains Numbers and `match` returns String in array, updating

Comment: This code seems to be the simplest and most elegant way of addressing the question asked.

Comment: @RichS Glad to hear that!

Comment: suggested edit.  Feel free to reject if it's not to your liking.  Basically edited to the part that gets right to the answer.

Comment: @Tushar to give more context, this would probably be too slow for me because I need to check a regex on the string every time, and the string is a line in a file which I iterate over, so that's probably too many checks.

Comment: Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @IlanBiala You can use `m` flag see https://regex101.com/r/xE7fG0/1, then you don't need to split the text by lines, use this regex directly on the file instead of using it on line

Comment: @Tushar that still means the regex is checking a ton of stuff, which I'd prefer not to do. Is there another solution you can think of?

Answer (score 1):

```
-?(?!(?:-?[012]\b)|10\b)\d+\b
```

Just add a `lookahead` removing the number you dont want.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/33

```
var re = /-?(?!(?:-?[012]\b)|10\b)\d+\b/gm; 
var str = '-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, or 10 -11, 8, -4, 11, 15, 121, 3';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: Test string: var a = "-11, 8, -4, 11, 15, 121, 3, abacoijaoiefjp -2 -1 0 ajoiefjaio 0 1 2 10"
a.match(/-?(?!(?:-?[012]\b)|10\b)\d+\b/) returns ["-11"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-?(?!([012]|10)\b)\d+\b` negative lookahead assertion will solve your problem

```js
var res = ' -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, or 10 11, 8, -4, 11, 15, 121, 3,'.match(/-?(?!([012]|10)\b)\d+\b/g);
console.log(res);
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/eC7dS9/2)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]